# Error using ncrack

Tags: passwords

I am trying to run a ncrack command of the following format:

`ncrack -P filePath1 filePath2 --user user1, user2, user3 ipAddress:port`

and I get the following error;

[image]

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-P` option doesn't take multiple arguments according to [the man page](http://nmap.org/ncrack/man.html), maybe concatenate the files at filePath1 and filePath2?

`ncrack -P filePath1 --user user1,user2,user3 ipAddress:port`

At least, that format just worked on my terminal.

From [the man page of ncrack](https://nmap.org/ncrack/man.html):

> `-P <filename>` (Specify password list)
>
> Specify your own password list by giving the path to the filename as argument to this option.

So this parameter takes only one argument.

On the other side

> Everything on the Ncrack command-line that isn't an option (or an option argument) is treated as a target host specification.

So this explains the errors displayed.

This can be verified: If you look closer into the [code](https://github.com/nmap/ncrack/blob/0e7c1b166ce91f980cffb05e1dc4d9e4d6f73d7b/TargetGroup.cc#L260)

[image: ncrack code]

you can see that if there is no IP delivered it tries to resolve the given hostname and if that fails ncrack shows this message.

Version 0.7 in comparison only displays one error message:

[image: ncrack 0.7 output]

and you have to delete the spaces between the users (which yields to `You must specify either a service name or a port (or both): user2,`).

So you can merge the two password files eg. using:

```
cat filePath1 filePath2 > filePath_merged
```

and call ncrack

```
ncrack -P filePath_merged --user user1,user2,user3 ipAddress:port
```